# Help with manipulating Cylindrical Laplacian and Fourier transforms for Harmonic Functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, cylindrical-coordinates

I have an issue when i try to follow the following reasoning [in Snieder book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMZYc.jpg) in a cylindrical coordinate system. To summarize the reasoning:

- consider a harmonic function V(x,z) so that its Laplacian is zero
  $\Delta V(x,z)=0$
- consider its Fourier transform over $x$, $v(k,z)$

\begin{array}{l}
V(x,z) = \int\limits_\infty  {v(k,z){e^{ikx}}dk} 
\end{array}

- expressing the cylindrical Laplacian (i must do it like that because my function of interest yields zero Laplacian using the cylindrical expression for the $x$ variable - my system is a bit unusual as i have to consider the $x$ variable to be cylindrical even though i work in a $xz$ plane, no angle involved)

*EDIT: example: the gravity field profile of a vertical cylinder at depth $z$ is expressed as $V(x,z)=\frac{1}{{\sqrt {{x^2} + {z^2}} }}$, with $x$ in $(-\infty,+\infty)$. Only the cylindrical Laplacian of this function is zero, not the cartesian.*

\begin{array}{l}
\Delta V(x,z) = \int\limits_\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\left( {x\frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}} \right) + \frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {z^2}}}} \right)\left[ {v(k,z){e^{ikx}}} \right]dk} \\
 = \int\limits_\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\left( {xikv(k,z){e^{ikx}}} \right) + \frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {z^2}}}(v(k,z){e^{ikx}})} \right)dk} \\
 = \int\limits_\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{x}ikv(k,z)\frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\left( {x{e^{ikx}}} \right) + \frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {z^2}}}(v(k,z){e^{ikx}})} \right)dk} \\
 = \int\limits_\infty  {\left( {\frac{{ik}}{x}v(k,z)\left( {{e^{ikx}} + xik{e^{ikx}}} \right) + \frac{{{\partial ^2}v(k,z)}}{{\partial {z^2}}}{e^{ikx}}} \right)dk} \\
 = \int\limits_\infty  {\left( {\frac{{ik(1 + ikx)}}{x}v(k,z) + \frac{{{\partial ^2}v(k,z)}}{{\partial {z^2}}}} \right){e^{ikx}}dk}  = 0
\end{array}

- The equation being equal to zero, and the term between brackets being the Fourier coefficients of the $\Delta V$, the Fourier coefficients can be equalled to zero, which yields the following PDE  :

$\frac{{{\partial ^2}v(k,z)}}{{\partial {z^2}}} - (k^2-\frac{{ik}}{x})v(k,z) =  0$

- To me this yields the following type of solution:

$v(k,z) = A(k)\exp \left( { + \sqrt {\left| {{k^2} - i\frac{k}{x}} \right|} .z} \right) + B(k)\exp \left( { - \sqrt {\left| {{k^2} - i\frac{k}{x}} \right|} .z} \right)$

I have some problems with this:

- $v(k,z)$ is not supposed to have any $x$ variable in it, because it is the Fourier transform of $V(x,z)$ along $x$
- Is there a fundamental error here? Or does it just mean that the general solutions do not apply in my case? (I'm not sure if that is even possible?)

I just don't know what to make of this situation. If someone sees a mistake in what I wrote, or can interpret what the apparent contradiction means, please point it out.

Comment: Why are you even transforming back? You should just be saying that since $\Delta V =0$ you have $\mathcal{F}(\Delta V)=0$ and then hopefully you can represent $\mathcal{F}(\Delta V)$ in terms of $\mathcal{F}(V)$.

Comment: Also I completely don't understand how you geometrically wound up with a situation where you get that as a Laplacian in a $xz$ plane. Either the whole thing is actually 3D and it's just radially symmetric, or the Laplacian should take its rectangular form, or somehow you have an operator that isn't actually the Laplacian.

Comment: Also you are Fourier transforming with respect to $x$ but presumably $x$ is in $(0,\infty)$ only so the usual identities for the Fourier transform will have boundary terms (i.e. the Fourier transform of $V_x$ will not be $ikv(k,z)$).

Comment: Thank you @ian. For your first question, the objective is in fact to express $v(k,z)$ and see its dependency on $z$. Concerning the geometrical situation, basically imagine a cylindrical space where i consider only the $\Theta=0$ case, and analyze the system in the resulting $xz$ plane (in fact the system has rotational symmetry). About the Laplacian, I know I need to use the cylindrical form because that's the one that gives me $\Delta V(x,z)=0$. Last point, yes you are right, in the cylindrical form indeed $x$ is in $(0,\infty)$. But why would the derivation not be $ikv(k,z)$?

Comment: If you fix $\Theta=0$ then the situation is rectangular, because you are in the $xz$ plane. It makes no sense to split the Laplacian in the polar way unless you are assuming that the problem is 3D but radially symmetric.

Comment: As for the derivative, just think about how you derive that result: you integrate by parts to move the derivative to the exponential. If you integrate by parts on an interval other than the whole line, you're going to have a boundary term that shows up.

Comment: Sorry i just edited my previous comment that the system has rotational symmetry. As i said i know the Laplacian has to be expressed in the cylindrical form because that's the one that gives me the zero Laplacian (i know $V(x,z)$), not the cartesian form.

Comment: OK, then it would be a bit less confusing if you used $r$. Anyway you still have the problem that to simplify the $(0,\infty)$ Fourier transform of the derivative, you need to do the integration by parts properly.

Comment: In fact I've thought of doing that, but then I hit another problem where the functions are commonly expressed with $x$ values in $(-\infty,+\infty)$, eg.
$\frac{1}{{\sqrt {{x^2} + {z^2}} }}$. I've noticed there's an issue here but this is what is in the literature. So I don't fully "dare" limiting the domain of $x$, so that's why I did not put $r$. The element where I'm sure is that the cylindrical Laplacian of my function, defined with $x$ in $(-\infty,+\infty)$, is zero.

Comment: That just doesn't make sense, I'd have to look into the context in more detail than I'm really willing to do for an MSE question in order to understand.

Comment: Context : the gravity field profile of a vertical cylinder ('ideal shape') is expressed as $\frac{1}{{\sqrt {{x^2} + {z^2}} }}$, with $x$ in $(0,+\infty)$. I amended the question to include that.

Comment: Hi @Ian , i'm trying to review my whole problem notably the variables. But there is still this point that i don't understand about the boundary terms you mention. I just don't see why I can't write $\frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}e^{ikx} = ike^{ikx}$. I don't even see where an integration by part happens. "you integrate by parts to move the derivative to the exponential" But the derivative is along $x$, the integral is along $k$. "the Fourier transform of $V_x$ will not be $ikv(k,z)$" did you mean derivative instead of FT? I feel lost here.

Comment: Consider for example $\int_0^\infty V_x(x,z) e^{-ikx} dx$. To find the Fourier transform of this in terms of the corresponding Fourier transform of $V$, you integrate by parts to move the derivative from $V$ to the exponential. So you wind up with $-V(0,z) + (ik) \int_0^\infty V(x,z) e^{-ikx} dx$. The latter term you identify as $ik v(k,z)$ (even though it isn't actually the "Fourier transform" of something). But the former term is still there!

Comment: Note that doing the integration on $(-\infty,\infty)$ by simply extending $V \equiv 0$ for $x<0$ *does not remove the problem* because then $V_x$ has a delta function contribution, unless you assume $V(0,z)=0$ (in which case the term drops out of course).